# A way to monitor how the focus out of an element happens in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing an element group and want to trigger some functionality when an elements' `focusout` event triggers.

But I have to monitor how the focusout happened, which cause the focus out.

Assume the `focusout` is bind for element A. if user click on the `element B` the focusout should call the `function_B`, if user click on the `element C` the focusout should call the `function_C`. And elements B,C should not be inside element A.

```
pseudo code : 

$( element_A ).focusout(function() {

   element_user_interaction = wether user clicks on element_B or element_C
   if(element_user_interaction == element_B){
        function_B();
   }else if(element_user_interaction == element_C){
        function_C();
   }

});
```

[I found a code from SO. see the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

I tried but could not change the above code to match for the pseudo code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the property of the event `relatedTarget`.

```
$( element_A ).focusout(function(e) {
   if(element_B.is(e.relatedTarget)){
        function_B();
   }else if(element_C.is(e.relatedTarget)){
        function_C();
   }
});
```

- For onfocus and onfocusin events, the related element is the element
  that LOST focus.
- For onblur and **onfocusout** events, the related
  element is the element that GOT focus.

Warning: This property is `null` if you click on something other than form elements i.e. image or text. Which is logical but could be confusing.

See more details at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_focus_relatedtarget.asp

Comment: World is full of surprises :-)

Comment: why i'm keep getting `null` for the `e.relatedTarget`

Comment: @prime Works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/3ku72Lnh/ So provide MCVE replicating your issue

Comment: it produces null if you click outside of any form elements. Which is logical. It only works on form elements as far as I see.

Comment: ah thanks for the fiddle. But try click out side an input tag. then it preints `null` any hack for that. :)

Comment: Updated my answer with that warning. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct one ;-)

Comment: @prime The workaround could be to make all non focusable elements focusable, e.g using: `$('*').filter(':not(:input)').attr('tabindex', -1);` But this would be better using pseudo jq UI selector `:focusable`. Here is an implementation e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/e1gkLzqz/

Comment: @Stepashka is there any way to make this work for non form elements as well. ?

Comment: @A.Wolff : this jsfiddle you gave not working when we open and test it in firefox. why is that.

Comment: @prime *Apparently*, that's a bug on FF regarding event relatedTarget https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=962251  Still not fixed... So my best bet would be to use a timeout and check for activeElement instead: http://jsfiddle.net/e1gkLzqz/1/